# Leaflet filter on geoJson properties : multiple criteria

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using Leaflet filter on geoJson data. I'm able to apply it with a simple criteria :

```
filter: function(feature, layer) {
     return feature.properties.field1 == "yes";
}
```

I can also apply two criteria with logical operators like `&&` or `||` :

```
filter: function(feature, layer) {
     return (feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "yes");
}
```

I want now to insert a condition (depending of a variable):

```
filter: function(feature, layer) {  
   if (varState == "01") {  
     return (feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "yes");
   }
   else if (varState == "02") {
     return (feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "no");
    }
    else {
      return feature.properties.field1 == "yes";            
    }
}
```

Does someone has already succeed this ?

Comment: what about defining two different layers for each filter. For example 
'var field1 = L.Geojson... filter: function() { field1 }' 
'var field2 = L.Geojson... filter: function() { field2 }'

Comment: Ok, and how can I use this two filters in a single layer ? (markers with `feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "yes";`

Comment: I can see no reason why this wouldn't work. Here's a quick test filtering some random data with multiple properties: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/am3nwqn8/ Have you made sure that there are actually features that have `"yes"` for both `field` and `field2`?

Comment: Yes, features have `"yes"` for both `field1` and `field2`

Comment: It works. I can't see it because I make a `if` `else if` `else` not recognize by filters.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where is varState defined, how do you call `L.geoJson`? I tried your filter and it works fine, see demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/akvCWSIF32JxWeAA82yb

Comment: `VarState` is defined at the beginnig, and change whith clicks. Now it works but I noticed that the layer must be defined in a function to be efficient. When click happened, I execute this function and filter operate. Result : [link](http://cocktaildata.fr/GIS/archeo/archeo.html)

Comment: I see no reason why 5 years old question should be changed, so last change was reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full answer with a `if ... else if ... else` condition :

```
filter: function(feature, layer) {  
   if (varState == "01") {  
     return (feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "yes");
   }
   else if (varState == "02") {
     return (feature.properties.field1 == "yes" && feature.properties.field2 == "no");
    }
    else {
      return feature.properties.field1 == "yes";            
    }
}
```